# Oracle Sql - Select customers with more than 1 order, listing one line for each order repeating column ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm newbie with SQL, and I trying several ways to solve something that seams to be a simple issue, but had no success at all.

I have two tables:

**CUSTOMERS**

```
ID_ |   EMAIL
----+------------------- 
01  |   JOHN@GMAIL.COM
02  |   MARY@HOTMAIL.COM
03  |   PAUL@LIVE.COM
```

**ORDERS**

```
ID  |   ID_ORDER    |   SKU
----+---------------+------
01  |   0101        |   123
01  |   0101        |   456
01  |   0102        |   789
02  |   0201        |   124
02  |   0201        |   562
03  |   0301        |   896
```

I need to list customers with more than one order getting the columns ID, EMAIL and ID_ORDER. My last try was:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.ID_, CUSTOMERS.EMAIL, ORDERS.ID_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMERS
JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID_ = ORDERS.ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID_
HAVING COUNT(CUSTOMERS.ID_) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the customers with more than 1 orders by grouping and then join to the tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.ID_, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDER
FROM (
  SELECT ID
  FROM ORDERS
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID_ORDER) > 1
) g 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.ID_ = g.ID   
INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON o.ID = c.ID_
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.ID_, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMERS c INNER JOIN ORDERS o 
ON o.ID = c.ID_
WHERE c.ID_ IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM ORDERS
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID_ORDER) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order ids together in one row, you need to aggregate them.  In Oracle, you can use `listagg()`:

```
SELECT c.ID_, c.EMAIL, LISTAGG(o.ID_ORDER, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY o.ID_ORDER) as id_orders
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON c.ID_ = o.ID
GROUP BY c.ID_, c.EMAIL
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

To get these on different rows, use window functions:

```
SELECT ID_, EMAIL, ID_ORDER
FROM (SELECT c.ID_, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDER,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c_ID_) as cnt
      FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN
           ORDERS o
           ON c.ID_ = o.ID
     ) c
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon!

Thanks for your help!

Actually LISTAGG do not solve my needs.


I need one line by each order, repeating the ID as a result like this:

ID | EMAIL                  | ID_ORDER
01 | JOHN@GMAIL.COM | 0101
01 | JOHN@GMAIL.COM | 0102